# How to convert a symbol into a number in Racket?

Tags: numbers, racket, symbols

I'm trying to turn 'red into 2, 'white into 9, 'brown into 1, and so on.

My code starts like this: (define (sum-of-colours colour1 colour2 colour3 ...)

I want the user to input symbols such as 'red, 'yellow, or 'black into colour1, colour2, etc... and then all the corresponding values get added up. Based on my current knowledge, I can't think of a way to directly turn symbols into numbers. Could someone give a hint about what should I do? Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classic lispy approach would be to use an *association list* to associate color symbols with numbers. An association list is a sort of dictionary which is itself a list of pairs to be associated. For example:

```
(define my-colors '((red 2)
                    (white 9)
                    (brown 1)))
```

Now one can get at the correct pair using the [`assoc`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=assoc#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assoc%29%29) function:

```
scratch.rkt> (assoc 'red my-colors)
'(red 2)
```

The number itself can be retrieved by using `second` on this result; but it is better to write an accessor function so that the implementation details of the dictionary can be changed without breaking code that uses the color dictionary. Further, using `second` directly on the result of `assoc` may fail since an input color symbol may not exist in the dictionary. This definition returns `#f` when a color symbol is not found:

```
(define (get-color c)
  (let ((entry (assoc c my-colors)))
    (if entry
        (second entry)
        #f)))
```

In Racket you could also use a hash table for this (other lisps have hash tables, too):

```
(define my-color-table (hash 'red 2
                             'white 9
                             'brown 1))
```

Now if you redefine `get-color` to make use of the new dictionary representation, other code that uses `get-color` will continue to work so long as the new definition preserves the interface:

```
(define (get-color c)
  (hash-ref my-color-table c #f))
```

The [`hash-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._hash-ref%29%29) function allows a *failure-result* to be specified; here when a key is not found, `#f` is returned, as before. This could be useful in a `sum-colors` function:

```
(define (sum-colors cs)
  (apply + (remove* '(#f)
                    (map get-color cs))))
```

Note that `sum-colors` does not care how the color dictionary is implemented, only that `get-color` knows how to retrieve color numbers from color symbols. Here, `map` is used to map the input list of color symbols to a list of color numbers. When a color symbol is not found, that symbol maps to `#f` in the list of color numbers. [`remove*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29) is used to remove all instances of `#f` before summing the list using `apply`. There are of course other ways to write this, and you may want some behavior other than to ignore unknown color symbols in the input.

Sample REPL interaction:

```
scratch.rkt> (sum-colors '(red brown))
3
scratch.rkt> (sum-colors '(red white purple green))
11
```

Comment: Got it, that really helped. Thank you so much!